# What is a typical tick interrupt duration in terms of CPU percentage?

Tags: interrupt, scheduler, duration, rtos

In many RTOS's the tick interrupt activates the scheduler which checks if higher priority task is ready to run and if so, performs a context switch. 
I wonder what is a typical duration of the tick interrupt in terms of CPU percentage? (When no context switch occurs).

Comment: I think that 0.1% of the CPU time is dedicated to the tick interrupt (scheduler doesn't perform context switch). Sounds reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the tick period/frequency. If there is a tick each 1 ms, then the percentage might be higher.

Also, it greatly depends on the processor and its clock speed. On an MPC5554 running at 128MHz, with cache enabled, the tick interrupt handling (i.e. only receiving the interrupt, looking at some conditions are returning to execution) is around 7 µs. This gives 0,07% on a 10 ms cycle/period.

Is this for an automotive application?